# passing lambda as a constructor argument

Tags: c++, lambda, functional-programming, c++14

I am trying to store a callback function in a class, so I can create different instances with different callback. Unfortunately stackoverflow forces me to write more useless stuff, saying my post is mostly code. However I don't see any troubles instantly understand my question by looking at the code below.

Can't understand why this doesn't work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class A {
    public:
        A(std::function<void()> lambda) : lambda_{lambda} {};
        void Run() { lambda_(); };
    private:
        std::function<void()> lambda_;
};

auto main() -> int {
    auto q = []{};    
    A(q) a;                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    a.Run();
}
```

Error:

```
1.cpp:15:10: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘a’
     A(q) a;
          ^
```

While this does:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void A(std::function<void()> lambda) {
    lambda(); 
};

auto main() -> int {
    auto q = []{};

    A(q);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The syntax for passing constructor arguments in a variable declaration is:

```
A a(q);
```

More generally, the different ways of declaring variables are:

```
TypeName variableName;    // no arguments
TypeName variableName();  // WRONG: this is a function declaration
TypeName variableName(arg1, arg2, ...);
```

And with C++11 [uniform initialization](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#uniform-init):

```
TypeName variableName{};  // no arguments
TypeName variableName{arg1, arg2, ...};
```

Comment: Don't forget about uniform initialization: ```TypeName variableName{};``` and ```TypeName variableName{arg1, arg2, ...};```

Comment: Thanks, I'll add that.

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax for initializing an object `a` with parameter `q` is

```
A a(q);
```

not

```
A(q) a;
```